# No Nice Menu navigation when logged in as admin

Tags: blocks, navigation

I just installed the Nice Menu module for drop-down support on in my theme. It looks all good when visiting the site anonymously, but when I'm logged in as admin the block "Header" doesn't display my menu. I've tried to find the problem under `/admin/structure/block` but couldn't, any hints?
I was able to get a comparison of both pages, side by side

**EDIT1**
left being the page in admin mode (no visible nice menu), right being the page in "normal" *anonymus* (nice menu visible) mode

[image]

The block seems to be visible on both sides... so why would it only display on one? :o

Comment: Do you have a different theme for administration?

Comment: check block settings, may be it's checked to show only for specific role.

Comment: @ShawnConn my admin theme is default, set to `seven` - page content should be displayed the same, should it not?

Comment: @WaQaRAli No, the `Roles` in my block settings are set to `not restricted`

Comment: @WaQaRAli, I'm trying to help deduce the issue. Block configurations are set per theme so I was wondering if both are admins/anons see the same theme, but not the same set of blocks.

Comment: @ShawnConn please see **EDIT1** above

Comment: @WaQaRAli please see **EDIT1** above

Comment: My guess is the administration theme or page CSS is conflicting with the nice menu CSS. You're need to inspect the rules triggering the nice menu behavior and see how it conflicts with your admin theme/page.